# Swapping class with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, swap, unique-ptr

```
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    unique_ptr<int> u;
    A(){}
    A(const A& other): u(new int(*other.u)){} // If I comment this out, it works.
    // A(A&&){} // This does not help.
};

int main() {
    A a;
    A b = a;
    swap(a, b);
}
```

This code does not work - fails with a wall of template errors saying `no matching function for call to ‘swap(A&, A&)’`. Why? Deleting the second constructor helps, but I need it in other code. I guessed it could be connected with automatical deleting of some constructors when other are defined, but manually adding move constructor does not help either. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are aware of that a `std::unique_ptr` object can't be copied? Therefore any attempt to implement any kind of copying (like having a copy-constructor) will cause the code to fail. For your class to have a copy-constructor makes no sense.

Comment: The code I wrote here is dummy. In real code, copy constructor does deep copy of underlying object.

Comment: If you are asking questions here, post the real code, not some vague approximation of it.

Comment: Well, I tried to reduce the code to smallest reproducible example. I doubt you want to read 300+ lines of implementation.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to show what I meant. The code is still small, though a bit cluttered with not-really-necessary addition.

Comment: @akrasuski1 This concept is called [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use it whenever you are able to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::swap()` requires its arguments to be *move-constructible* and *move-assignable*.

Given:

```
struct A {
    unique_ptr<int> u;
    A();
};
```

`A` is swappable, thanks to the implicitly defined move-constructor and move-assignment operators.

But, given:

```
struct A {
    unique_ptr<int> u;
    A();
    A(A const&);
};
```

By declaring a user defined copy constructor, you're inhibiting the implicit definition of `A`'s move constructor and move assignment operator 
(and by having a non-assignable-copyable member, you're inhibiting the implicit generation of `A`'s copy constructor and copy assignment operator).

To make `A` swappable again, you need to either user-define *both* (*):

```
struct A {
    unique_ptr<int> u;
    A();
    A(A const&);
    A(A&&);
    A& operator=(A&&);
};
```

or neither, and just add proper copy-assignment:

```
struct A {
    unique_ptr<int> u;
    A();
    A(A const&);
    A& operator=(A const&);
};
```

but, this will probably defeat your original intent of avoiding deep copies on swap, so you'll probably end up defining all of them anyway.

---

(*) *noexcept* specifications omitted just for brevity ...

Comment: In this case, you can define move ctor simply as `A(A&&) = defalut;`.

Comment: @DanielLangr sure, but in order to *correctly* define them we'd need to know the exact semantics of A (that we don't know, being a dummy example); defaulting them may result in breaking A's actual invariants, that's the very reason why the language does not define them for us automatically ...

Comment: You’re right, that’s why I wrote “in this case”. I meant “this definition of `A`”.

Comment: Another option is simply to override `swap()` with `A&` parameters, and then have it swap the `u` objects directly. Then you don't have to add move semantics to `A` if you don't want to

Comment: Not both, but in fact neither. A type whose copy c'tor and assignment operator accept a **const** lvalue ref, is move constructible and assignable. The problem here is that the copy c'tor inhibits the implicit move c'tor, while the `unique_ptr` member inhibits the implicit copy assignment operator.

Comment: @StoryTeller edited ... I've been a bit reluctant to change my answer, because I had the impression the op goal was to avoid deep copies on swap, hence having no move at all would have been the wrong solution; that said, I agree it makes little sense to have a copy-ctor but no copy-op (although we really don't know the actual op use case) ...

Comment: I don't object to your proposed solution, just to be clear. I think any class that needs to perform deep copies better implement efficient moving (because why not really!?). I just felt you misrepresented the core of the problem with the OP. Any way, great answer.